# Inter referencing vs external referencing

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have to design a table(s) with a parent and child relationship (category and sub category)
Is it better to have two tables with the parent_id as a foreign key in the child table or having one table with parent_id as on column.

Comment: My choice is keeping both in one table. Records which don't have any parent should contain -1 else the parent id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IF* the main category and the subcategory have the *same* schema, one table.

*IF* they have different schemas, two tables.  An example of "doing this wrong" was a forum (or email) schema that tried to put `Threads` and `Messages` into the same table.

The 'top' category can have its `parent_id` equal to 0 or NULL.  The subcategories should have `parent_id` set to the `id` of the immediate parent.  Note that this provides arbitrary nesting of categories (in a tree, no loops, etc).

Answer (score 0):

you can try using one table, just add a column "has_child" for the parent category with value of 1 if it has child and 0 if none, then for the child category you can have a "parent_id" with values > 0 if it has a parent, if none just 0

Comment: I know the logic, My question is what is better with regards to optimization.

Comment: `has_child` is rarely needed -- simply do a "self-join" to discover whether there are children or not.

Comment: your question is which is better "to have two tables" or "have one table" ? ,
my suggestion is "have one table". :))